# How to select the last child of only first level children nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="chatbox">
  <div style="margin-left: 400px">
      <div></div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 800px">
      <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

var size = $( ".chatbox" ).last().css("margin-left");
```

I want to select the div with style="margin-left: 800px"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the direct-descendent selector `>`, which will limit the collection to the first level of children:

```
$( ".chatbox" ).find('> div').last().css("margin-left");
```

Comment: I think this is not a very good practice because jQuery finds the right side selectors first and then looks for the left side ones. It's almost always better to use `find`, `children` and other such methods instead of multiple selectors, - https://jsperf.com/random-jquery-test-994739/1

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
$(".chatbox").children().last()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use last child element with the direct-descendent selector ">" this. It is fully tested. Here is the code:

> $( ".chatbox" ).find('> div:last-child').css("margin-left");